# React constructor declare props crash intellisense vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, frontend

Any raison why i cant declare my default props like this ?
Am new in modern front-end and am come from js vanilla, sorry if seem hard to me understand the logic !

```js
class MenueButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = {
            /**@type {number} description*/
            count: props?.count || 0,
            /**@type {string} description*/
            test2: props?.test2 || '',
        }
    }
```

this append if a avoid to pass all props defined ex: `<MenueButtons count='0' />`
[image]
`` Warning: MenueButtons(...): When calling super() in `MenueButtons`, make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed. ``

the only way i can see is proceed like this after the class !

```js
MenueButtons.defaultProps = {
    count: 0,
    test2: '',
};
```

But for me it look weird, and **i lost my intellisense in VsCode** !
Any way to declare my props in constructor and get intellisense work fine ?

I try declare in constructor because it the only way to get intelligence work like this.
Declare with `defaultProps` , break suggest and declarative check.

---

with declare in constructor
[image]
[image]

---

with declare only defaultProps 
[image]

---

**EDIT:**
Ok after many test, this look more intuitive and logic for me.
100% compatible with intellisense from vsCode IDE.

```js
/**Class description */
class MenueButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        /**@type {{aaa?: number, bbb?: string }} */
        this.props
    }

    render() {
```

not yet perfect, **if you have other cleaner idea**, or more logic, i am open to any suggestion thank you.
I can maybe also create a `typedef` top of the document for share in `defaultProps` !

```js
    /**
        * @typedef {Object} _defaultProps - ...descriptions
        * @property {number} [_defaultProps.aaa] - ...descriptions
        * @property {string} [_defaultProps.bbb] - ...descriptions
    */
```

```
       /**@type {_defaultProps} */
        this.props
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main problem here is that you try to reassign `this.props`. Props should be treated as read-only data within your component.

Comment: hey thanks ! you give me a idea !
This seem work

```
        super(props);
        /**@type {{aaa?: number, bbb?: string }} */
        this.props
```

Comment: finally solved with `react-easy-state` https://github.com/RisingStack/react-easy-state